# Append operation between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform an append operation between two dataframes with a "For" loop, but this method does not work!

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df1)):
    df2.append(df1.iloc[i])
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This method works well on lists

How can I use this method for pandas?

I want every row that was approved by me to be added to the empty list of the df2 dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

`Append` was replaced by `concat`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1.iloc[i]], axis=1)
```